# Areapath is not correct in programmatically generated TFS/VSTS workitem

Tags: rest, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to create workitem in TFS/VSTS with custom area-path

for example I want to be my  workitem areapath to be "cde"

Area-paths in my project are similar to below

[image]

My patch element for area-path is as below.

```
{
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.AreaPath",
    "value": "VSTS_TFS_Test\abc\cde"
  }
```

I am using batch create method for this hence REST call url is as below

```
<<my tfs collection url>>/_apis/wit/$batch?api-version=1.0
```

However this always just display project file (VSTS_TFS_Test) as area in work item. Please refer below screen.

[image]

I wanted to "cde" to be area in work item. Please provide some guidence to make this possible

references :
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem should be your patch element.

Just try below patch element:

```
{
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.AreaPath",
    "value": "VSTS_TFS_Test\\abc\\cde"
}
```

After the patch, just refresh your browser to check the work item again.